# Copy png from each dir, if png is >600x600?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a tree of directories with png files in each.

From each directory would I like to copy those png files where their resolution is >(600x600).

Using the following to commands could I create a script that would do just that, but it would be fairly long.

This command will list png's where the horizonal number of pixels is >600.

```
for f in *.png;do if [ `file $f | cut -f5 -d\ ` -gt 600 ] ; then echo $f;fi;done
```

This command will find all dirs and copy file.png to them

```
find <basedir>/ -type d -exec cp file.png '{}' \;
```

Does someone know of a good way to solve this problem?

**Update**:
This is what I got.

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name *png -print0); do
    identify -format '%w %h' $f|awk '{print $1 $2}'

# if [$1 -gt 600 && $2 -gt 600]; then
    cp $f ~/600x600
    fi

done
```

How do I use `$1` and `$2` from `awk` in the `if`-statement?

Comment: Do you want to copy them to a single folder? Do you want to keep directory structure?

Comment: Your commands confuse me. The find command copies a single file to many subdirectories. How is this relevant to your question?

Comment: @onteria_ 18 To a single directory.

Comment: with your updated code I have added a workable solution to my answer. I had most of it typed out awhile ago, however, was interrupted. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
identify -format '%w %h' yourImage.png
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, i had most of this typed out awhile ago, but was interupted.

I tested this, and it should work

```
for f in *png; 
do 
  identify -format '%w %h' $f | awk -v f="$f" '{ if ($1 >= 600 && $2 >= 600) print "cp -piv "f" ~/DESTINATION_DIR"}' | bash
done
```

notice that you can do the comparison inside awk. If you have a desire to learn, try making this a one-liner. Sure, it will be long, but you should be able to do this entire operation with find. the problem for me is piping inside -exec, but I know its possible.

Comment: just to redirect formatted command lines with awk to bash in order to execute them.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure to understand the question, but i guess you want to copy file with size greater than 600x600 into a specific directory, then you can do something like :

```
for f in *.png;do if [[ `file $f | cut -f5 -d\ ` -gt 600 ]] ; then 
echo $f;fi;done|nawk '{print "cp "$1" my_specific_directory"}' | bash
```

where my_specific_directory is the directory where you want to copy your pngs...